# How to access tr tag that is using certain attribute instead of class attribute?

Tags: javascript, cheerio

I am currently using cheerio in JavaScript, but I don't know how to access a `tr` tag that is using a certain attribute instead of a `class` attribute.

For example,

```
<tr role="work" class="c1">
    <td>task1</td>
    <td>task2</td>
</tr>
<tr role="work" class="c2">
    <td>task1</td>
    <td>task2</td>
</tr>
```

I tried some of the advice that I received like...

```
$("tr[role='work']").each(function(i, el) {
    ...
}
```

to get all `tr` tags with `role=work`, but it isn't working as I was planning it to be.

Comment: your advice was sound, double-check your inputs and code

Comment: Yep, that really should work. When you output `$("tr[role='work']")`, what kind of selection do you get? What's not working as you expect it to work?

Comment: I tried setting 

$("tr[role='work']").each(function(i, el) {
    console.log("check");
}

and it would not print anything out..

Comment: Does it make any difference if this "tr" tag that I'm trying to get at is placed in this order?

"body,div,div,div,div,div,div,table,tbody,tr"

so inside of body, i have to go through 6 divs and table inside has tbody which contains the "tr" tag that I'm trying to go to.

But this tr has unique role.

Is :

    $("tr[role='work']").each(function(i, el) {
        ...
    }

still good to use??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this.

### Without jQuery

```
document.querySelectorAll('tr[role="work"]');
```

Which will give you a list of elements, which I personally like to use.

### jQuery

```
$('tr[role="work"]')
```

This one returns elements differently since they are in jquery's own special format.

Comment: This seems much simpler, so I will try this.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

While this is kinda ugly (and not using JQuery), I used this to check for elements with a specific role:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    var elem = elements[i];
    if(elem.attributes && elem.attributes.role && elem.attributes.role.value === 'work') {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: named props on the dom0 `attributes` interface? `node.value`? yikes. it works, but this is really not the dom interaction style to suggest to others to use; it's slow, fragile, and wordy.

Comment: yea thats true... It really IS ugly! JQuery has a .attr('role') getter which probably is the only way to get an arbitrary attribute (aside from the selector, which should actually work like he posted)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Or you could just do `document.querySelectorAll('tr').filter(function(element) { return element.getAttribute('role') === 'work'; })` if you really want to go this route. Otherwise use my above answer.